# Why did acos(10.0) stop setting errno to EDOM when I upgraded from GCC 9.2 to 10.2?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, errno

I'm using version 10.2 of the GNU (GCC) Toolchain for the ARM platform:

https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads

In particular the Windows (mingw-w64-i686) hosted cross compilers AArch64 bare-metal target (aarch64-none-elf) version.

I've noticed some odd behavior regarding the value of errno.

Here's a quick snippet (**TEST.C**):

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double val = 0.0;
    errno = 0;
    val = acos(10.0);
    printf("errno = %d\n", errno);
    return 0;
}
```

errno returns 0 in 10.2, while if I use 9.2 of the toolchain errno will return 33 (EDOM) as 10.0 is out of range for the acos function.

I've looked at the GCC change log between 9.2 and 10.2 and don't see anything that would explain the different behavior.

Anyone encounter a similar problem?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/math_errhandling

Comment: @KamilCuk, wrong language [correct page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/math_errhandling)

Comment: Updated to set errno before calling acos, no difference.  In fact, it seems acos will never write to errno in 10.2.  I tried log(0) and that correctly sets errno.  It seems that the behavior of acos may have changed between 9.2 and 10.2.

Comment: I think `acos` is _not_ in `gcc` but in `libm` so you may want to look at the change log for the latter. You may want to diff the source as well.

Comment: Right, check whether the two toolchains are using different versions of the math library. gcc itself just sees `acos(10.0)` as a function call.

Comment: Appreciate all the suggestions, looks like 9.2 is packaged with the glibc 2.30 and 10.2 is packaged with 2.31.  Release notes don't reveal anything obvious.  Looking through the source code, but it's a bit cryptic.